How to export each individual record as its own PDF?
I'm trying to export each record as its own PDF and save it to a specific file location.
The database has one table, one query, and one report. There are 217 records, so I'd like 217 pdf files.
I want the PDF name to be based on the record ID specified within the table (ex: Record 1 would be saved as "Record1.pdf", record 2 would be saved as "Record2.pdf", etc.).
My report name is "Emails".
My query name is "Query1".
I've taken bits and pieces from the internet.
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim ReportName As String
    Dim OutputFolder As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    ReportName = "Emails"
    OutputFolder = "C:\Users\MyName"
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Query1")
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewReport, "[ID] = " & rs![ID] & " ", acHidden
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , "", acFormatPDF, OutputFolder & "\" & rs![ID] & ".PDF"
        DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName, acSaveYes
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub

This code exports one PDF (named "1.pdf") and saves it to my file location, however all records are within this PDF. The code then fails.

Do you use Option Explicit?

There are other "quirks". You mistyped acFormactPDF ,  Dim OutpoutFolder As String and then OutputFolder = "C:\Users\MyName". And you use Set db = Nothing and do not declare db or use it anywhere.

Not sure what Option Explicit is. I did adjust those typos and removed the db.

Actually, yes I did use Option Explicit.

You entered the filter as 3rd argument, i.e., as FilterName instead of WhereCondition (4th argument). Specify the parameter name explicitly: oCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewReport, WhereCondition := "[ID] = " & rs![ID], WindowMode := acHidden. See: DoCmd.OpenReport-Methode (Access).

You miss a comma:
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewReport, , "[ID] = " & rs![ID] & "", acHidden


The  & "" is not required. It is often made wrong assumption that a string must be terminated by a double quote. String literals (string constants as they appear in code) must be enclosed in double quotes but not the string values. "[ID] = " & rs![ID] creates a string value [ID] = 15 (as an example), which is totally fine. Adding an empty string doesn't change this value.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes: I know. It is coding style to indicate that the string ends here and single-quotes wrapping text variables are not in use.
